# Send and Receive data to Web Server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ms-access

What is a good way to Send data to a web server and then receive and port the data to a Microsoft Access database on the web server?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Send data how and from where?

Comment: Are you asking how to do an http post or are you trying to build the receiving service?

Comment: Data to come from a program on our Internal server, possibly from field entries and/or from sql server.

Comment: @Chris Lively Trying to do both. Maybe WebClientUpload for Posting and I need something to recieve to. Not quite sure how to do this effecively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need some tutorials.  Here's one.

http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/building-web-service-aspnet-35

Note that there are MANY different ways to create a web service and consume it.

Examples include: Generic Handlers (.ashx), MS Web Services (.asmx), WCF services (.svc), etc.

All of them have features / benefits.  Probably the easiest one by far is to use generic handlers which are great for building RESTful type services.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the link you sent. From what I was told was we needed a way to send chunks of data (live) to the web server and consume it by adding to database or for whatever reason.

Comment: I've looked into the tutorial and an msdn video as well( http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet). I get the concept, but how about sending objects, say a datatable, generic list, or even a 1000 rows of data?

Comment: @tmax: Package the data up into json or xml and post it.  The receiving server could rip it apart and do whatever it needs to.

Comment: @Chris: Ok, that makes sense. So far WebServices seem the way to go. I've also seen other methods such as HttpWebRequest and WebClient.UploadStringAsync. Out of the 3 what seems to be the most flexixble and/or recommended avenue?

Comment: @tmax: We've tried all of the approaches I mentioned above. WCF - complicated setup with features that most sites just don't need. ASMX services - strong dependency on XML can cause issues with certain clients. Generic Handlers - Extremely easy to code, lightweight, and fast performing; everything that can post to an http server can use them.

Comment: @tmax:  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573563/building-a-c-web-api-rest/5573624#5573624